# Generate SQL query results in specific XML format

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm looking to generate an XML output in the following example format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PSD006-ShortTermLoans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1 PSD006-Schema.xsd" xmlns="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1">
<PSDFeedHeader>
  <Submitter>
   <SubmittingFirm>713984</SubmittingFirm>
  </Submitter>
  <ReportDetails>
   <ReportCreationDate>2020-04-23</ReportCreationDate>
   <ReportIdentifier>PSD006_713984__50</ReportIdentifier>
  </ReportDetails>
</PSDFeedHeader>
<PSD006FeedMsg>
  <CoreItems>
   <FirmReferenceNumber>713984</FirmReferenceNumber>
   <TransRef>713984_D000147827</TransRef>
   <Cancellation>false</Cancellation>
  </CoreItems>
  <ShortTermLoans>
   <TransactionDate>2020-03-21</TransactionDate>
   <LoanAmount>1000</LoanAmount>
   <LoanType>HCST</LoanType>
   <APR>399.41</APR>
   <ArrangementFee>0</ArrangementFee>
   <TotalAmountPayable>1834</TotalAmountPayable>
   <Rollover>N</Rollover>
   <OrderOfRollover>0</OrderOfRollover>
   <LengthOfTerm>272</LengthOfTerm>
   <ReasonForLoan>P</ReasonForLoan>
   <DOBOfBorrower>1979-10-07</DOBOfBorrower>
   <PostCode>N14 6HE</PostCode>
   <MonthlyIncomeOfBorrower>3166</MonthlyIncomeOfBorrower>
   <MaritalStatusOfBorrower>O</MaritalStatusOfBorrower>
   <ResidentialStatusOfBorrower>X</ResidentialStatusOfBorrower>
   <EmploymentStatusOfBorrower>EF</EmploymentStatusOfBorrower>
  </ShortTermLoans>
</PSD006FeedMsg>
</PSD006-ShortTermLoans>
```

This is sample data which is required in the XML format above.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Loans ( [Transref] varchar(16), [TransactionDate] date, [OriginalAdvance] money, [LoanType] varchar(4), [ContractualAPR] float(8), [OriginalProjectedTotalRepayable] money, [OriginalTerm] int, [ReasonforLoan] varchar(4), [DOB] date, [Postcode] varchar(8), [Salary] int, [SalaryFrequency] int, [ResidentialStatus] int, [EmploymentStatus] int )
INSERT INTO #Loans
VALUES
( '11', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 300.0000, 'HCST', 790, 1000.0000, 6, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '12', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 99.9, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '13', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 99.9, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '14', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 99.9, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '17', N'2020-08-15T00:00:00', 750.0000, 'HCST', 392.71, 1000.0000, 9, 'HCST', N'1995-01-01T00:00:00', 'SE21 8NZ', 15000, 1508, 1472, 449 ), 
( '17', N'2020-08-15T00:00:00', 750.0000, 'HCST', 392.71, 1000.0000, 9, 'HCST', N'1995-01-01T00:00:00', 'SE21 8NZ', 15000, 1508, 1472, 449 ), 
( '20', N'2020-07-30T00:00:00', 800.0000, 'HCST', 399.4, 1000.0000, 9, 'HCST', N'1985-03-12T00:00:00', 'EH21 6UH', 21000, 1499, 1477, 500 ), 
( NULL, N'2020-08-05T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 790, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1980-07-07T00:00:00', 'BD1 3LY', 2000, 1508, 1481, 470 ), 
( '37', N'2020-08-22T00:00:00', 300.0000, 'HCST', 792.4, 1000.0000, 6, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 35000, 1508, NULL, 470 ), 
( '38', N'2020-08-19T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 790, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1990-07-07T00:00:00', 'BD1 3LY', 2000, 1508, 1481, 470 )
```

This is my query so far:

```
     SELECT 

        (

           SELECT '99999' AS Submitter

           FOR XML PATH('SubmittingFirm'), ROOT ('PSDFeedHeader'), TYPE

       ),
       (
           SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS ReportCreationDate,
           'PSD006_713984__51' AS ReportIdentifier
                  
           FOR XML PATH('ReportDetails'),  ROOT ('PSDFeedHeader'), TYPE
       ),


       
       (
           SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #Loans FOR XML PATH('ShortTermLoans'), TYPE
       )

FOR XML RAW(''), ROOT('PSD006-ShortTermLoans'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

Which gives the XML below and as you can see I've made some progress however I'm having difficulty nesting the selects. For example the Submitter and ReportDetails node should be nested within the PSDFeedHeader node.

```
       <PSD006-ShortTermLoans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <PSDFeedHeader>
    <SubmittingFirm>
      <Submitter>99999</Submitter>
    </SubmittingFirm>
  </PSDFeedHeader>
  <PSDFeedHeader>
    <ReportDetails>
      <ReportCreationDate>24/09/2020</ReportCreationDate>
      <ReportIdentifier>PSD006_713984__51</ReportIdentifier>
    </ReportDetails>
  </PSDFeedHeader>
  <ShortTermLoans>
    <Transref>11</Transref>
    <TransactionDate>2020-06-22</TransactionDate>
    <OriginalAdvance>300.0000</OriginalAdvance>
    <LoanType>HCST</LoanType>
    <ContractualAPR>7.9000000e+002</ContractualAPR>
    <OriginalProjectedTotalRepayable>1000.0000</OriginalProjectedTotalRepayable>
    <OriginalTerm>6</OriginalTerm>
    <ReasonforLoan>HCST</ReasonforLoan>
    <DOB>1999-01-31</DOB>
    <Postcode>HG2 9DX</Postcode>
    <Salary>20000</Salary>
    <SalaryFrequency>1508</SalaryFrequency>
    <ResidentialStatus>1486</ResidentialStatus>
    <EmploymentStatus>470</EmploymentStatus>
  </ShortTermLoans>
</PSD006-ShortTermLoans>
```

Comment: It is not clear how two `<Transref>` elements you got are fitting to the desired output. Please clarify.

Comment: We are providing a list of loan numbers and associated details to the FCA. The Transref is the loan number and according to their example XML, each Transref has a <PSD006FeedMsg> node and the associated loan elements under both the <CoreItems> and <ShortTermLoans> nodes.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Please use a single mock table to simulate all the joins for (1) above

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I've updated the question with sample data and my workings so far. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your original post and provide (3) a desired output based on the loans table data sample, i.e. (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to construct desired XML via XQuery and FLWOR expression.

If needed, you can apply the same method of using SQL variables for the rest of the hard-coded values inside XML.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @loans TABLE ( [Transref] varchar(16), [TransactionDate] date, [OriginalAdvance] money, [LoanType] varchar(4), [ContractualAPR] float(8), [OriginalProjectedTotalRepayable] money, [OriginalTerm] int, [ReasonforLoan] varchar(4), [DOB] date, [Postcode] varchar(8), [Salary] int, [SalaryFrequency] int, [ResidentialStatus] int, [EmploymentStatus] int )
INSERT INTO @Loans
VALUES
( '11', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 300.0000, 'HCST', 790, 1000.0000, 6, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '12', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 99.9, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '13', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 99.9, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '14', N'2020-06-22T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 99.9, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 20000, 1508, 1486, 470 ), 
( '17', N'2020-08-15T00:00:00', 750.0000, 'HCST', 392.71, 1000.0000, 9, 'HCST', N'1995-01-01T00:00:00', 'SE21 8NZ', 15000, 1508, 1472, 449 ), 
( '17', N'2020-08-15T00:00:00', 750.0000, 'HCST', 392.71, 1000.0000, 9, 'HCST', N'1995-01-01T00:00:00', 'SE21 8NZ', 15000, 1508, 1472, 449 ), 
( '20', N'2020-07-30T00:00:00', 800.0000, 'HCST', 399.4, 1000.0000, 9, 'HCST', N'1985-03-12T00:00:00', 'EH21 6UH', 21000, 1499, 1477, 500 ), 
( NULL, N'2020-08-05T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 790, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1980-07-07T00:00:00', 'BD1 3LY', 2000, 1508, 1481, 470 ), 
( '37', N'2020-08-22T00:00:00', 300.0000, 'HCST', 792.4, 1000.0000, 6, 'HCST', N'1999-01-31T00:00:00', 'HG2 9DX', 35000, 1508, NULL, 470 ), 
( '38', N'2020-08-19T00:00:00', 1000.0000, 'HCST', 790, 1000.0000, 12, 'HCST', N'1990-07-07T00:00:00', 'BD1 3LY', 2000, 1508, 1481, 470 );
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @SubmittingFirm VARCHAR(20) = '713984'
    , @ReportCreationDate DATE = GETDATE()
    , @Cancellation VARCHAR(10) = 'false';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS [xsi]
    , DEFAULT 'urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1')
SELECT (
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM @loans
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<PSD006-ShortTermLoans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1 PSD006-Schema.xsd"
                       xmlns="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1">
<PSDFeedHeader>
    <Submitter>
        <SubmittingFirm>{sql:variable("@SubmittingFirm")}</SubmittingFirm>
    </Submitter>
    <ReportDetails>
        <ReportCreationDate>{sql:variable("@ReportCreationDate")}</ReportCreationDate>
        <ReportIdentifier>PSD006_713984__50</ReportIdentifier>
    </ReportDetails>
</PSDFeedHeader>
<PSD006FeedMsg>
    <CoreItems>
        <FirmReferenceNumber>{sql:variable("@SubmittingFirm")}</FirmReferenceNumber>
        <TransRef>713984_D000147827</TransRef>
        <Cancellation>{sql:variable("@Cancellation")}</Cancellation>
    </CoreItems>
{
    for $x in /root/r
    return <ShortTermLoans>{$x/*}</ShortTermLoans>
}
</PSD006FeedMsg>
</PSD006-ShortTermLoans>');
```

**Output**

```
<PSD006-ShortTermLoans xmlns="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD006:1 PSD006-Schema.xsd">
  <PSDFeedHeader>
    <Submitter>
      <SubmittingFirm>713984</SubmittingFirm>
    </Submitter>
    <ReportDetails>
      <ReportCreationDate>2020-09-24</ReportCreationDate>
      <ReportIdentifier>PSD006_713984__50</ReportIdentifier>
    </ReportDetails>
  </PSDFeedHeader>
  <PSD006FeedMsg>
    <CoreItems>
      <FirmReferenceNumber>713984</FirmReferenceNumber>
      <TransRef>713984_D000147827</TransRef>
      <Cancellation>false</Cancellation>
    </CoreItems>
    <ShortTermLoans>
      <Transref>11</Transref>
      <TransactionDate>2020-06-22</TransactionDate>
      <OriginalAdvance>300.0000</OriginalAdvance>
      <LoanType>HCST</LoanType>
      <ContractualAPR>7.9000000e+002</ContractualAPR>
      <OriginalProjectedTotalRepayable>1000.0000</OriginalProjectedTotalRepayable>
      <OriginalTerm>6</OriginalTerm>
      <ReasonforLoan>HCST</ReasonforLoan>
      <DOB>1999-01-31</DOB>
      <Postcode>HG2 9DX</Postcode>
      <Salary>20000</Salary>
      <SalaryFrequency>1508</SalaryFrequency>
      <ResidentialStatus>1486</ResidentialStatus>
      <EmploymentStatus>470</EmploymentStatus>
    </ShortTermLoans>
  </PSD006FeedMsg>
</PSD006-ShortTermLoans>
```

Comment: That is simply brilliant and exactly what I wanted. @YitzhakKhabinsky

Comment: @TheCoxta, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: Hi @YitzhakKhabinsky - I'm looking to make a slight change to my original request. Shall I create a new post or update this one? What's the correct process? –

Comment: @TheCoxta, you would need to ask a new question.